# How to include a full column using a join

Tags: mysql

I'm doing an homework assignment and I have most of it but I can't get the last part. I don't know how to "Include artists without albums in your listing"?

```
SELECT
    artist.name, Title
FROM
    artist    
INNER JOIN
    album ON artist.artistID = album.artistid 
ORDER BY
    name, title;
```

This is what I get (top) and what I'm supposed to get (bottom):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` in this case.

Different joins explanation with examples could be found in many places, for example in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Comment: It will be nice if you explain the reasons behind that change, or at least  some reference to the documentation so she can learn about it. This answer like this can be just a commentary.